# neural network performance almost the same for different types of architectures

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm trying to predict a numerical value (regression problem) for which I have implemented a neural network of 5 inputs and one output. I have tried different hyperparameters, particularly the number of layers (1-5) and neurons per layer (8, 16, 32, 64, 128). However, the performances are almost the same for all configurations.

Is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong? can a model with 1 layer have the same performance as another with 5 layers?
Also, What can I do to improve the predictions?

My dataset has1191355 rows. Here are few samples:

```
       Input1  Input2     Input3  Input4   Input5   Output
0      149039   63329        0       1        10    2458.0
1      147050  148259        0       1        10     151.0
2      159550  166727        0       1        10    1388.0
3      134486  129650        0       1        10     409.0
4      134678  124667        0       1        10    1047.0
```

Here's a sample of code:

```
nblayers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nbunits = [8, 16, 32, 64, 128]

for l in range(len(nblayers)):
for u in range(len(nbunits)):
    lyr = nblayers[l]
    unt = nbunits[u]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(5,)))

    add_layer(model, nblayers[l], nbunits[u])    # adds Dense layers to the model 
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss=['mean_absolute_error'],
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=[metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(),
                           metrics.MeanAbsolutePercentageError(),
                           _mean_relative_error(normalizer=[1]),
                           metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=11, callbacks=[early])
    x = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    rs = [lyr, unt, x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]]
    results = pd.DataFrame([rs])
    results.to_csv(res, mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

The results I have obtained are mentioned here :

[image: |Layers|Units|Loss|MAE|MAPE|MRE|RMSE| |-|-|-|-|-|-|-| |1 | 8 | 354.5303345 | 354.5303345|108.9388657|1.089386821|1946.536255| |1 | 16 | 354.5303345 | 354.5303345|108.9388657|1.089386821|1946.536255| |1 | 32 | 354.5303345 | 354.5303345|108.9388657|1.089386821|1946.536255| |1 | 64 | 354.5303345 | 354.5303345|108.9388657|1.089386821|1946.536255| |1 | 128 | 354.5303345 | 354.5303345|108.9388657|1.089386821|1946.536255|]

Comment: What loss you get if nblayers = 0 ?

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov 451.9438

Comment: Is this normal? Can be, mostly it depends on data, one need to analyse it.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov How so?

Comment: Well, i'll suggest to begin with a look at some basic free courses, namely this one https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intro-to-machine-learning and this https://www.kaggle.com/learn/feature-engineering